# Enable hook only when required for caching

Tags: reactjs, typescript, caching

I have a hook which calls a third party library to get live market data from an RPC

```
const refreshedData = usePriceData(chainId, tokenList).priceData
```

This call returns new data each time and cannot be refactored because its in a third party library.

I would like to cache the pairs returned from the hook on a 5 minute interval so I'm doing the following

```
//Pseudo code
const refreshedData = usePriceData(chainId, tokenList).priceData; 
const cacheData = () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_PRICE_DATA', payload: calculatePrices(refreshedData) });
};

useEffect(() => {
  // Initial fetch when the component mounts
  cacheData();

  // Set up interval for subsequent fetches
  const intervalId = setInterval(cacheData, refreshInterval);

  return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, [chainId, tokenList, refreshInterval, dispatch]);

function calculatePrices(priceData: any) {
   //... do calulations
}
```

Basically this is working to cache the calculations from the refreshed data fine, but the `usePriceData(chainId, tokenList).priceData` call will waste cycles continually getting refreshed price data that isn't going to be used.

Since the `usePriceData` is external and cannot be modified, and conditional hooks are not allowed in react,  How can I only grab the price data when its required for the cache?

I'm thinking it would be possible if I just mount and unmount a component when the interval elapses.

How can I enable the price data hook only when its required to refresh the cache?